# Configuring pgAdmin4 to work as webpage

Tags: python, apache, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I have installed pgAdmin4 with postgres 9.6.8 on my local computer (Windows 7 x64). I want to access pgadmin by web interface but this really doesn't work. I tried to configure apache24, python 3.4 and pgadmin4 using those articles

https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/server_deployment.html

https://beamtic.com/installing-mod-wsgi-apache-windows

Unfortunately it isn't working for me - apache starts, virtual host file is loaded but nothing happens.
What I did was to install apache and configuring it to work with mod_wsgi.so.  Then I added some configuration entries (based on articles above).

Could some one explain me step by step how to configure pgadmin/apache/python to work with pgadmin web interface? Maybe is some installer for windows what have this configuration included?

This is very complicated for me because I don't know python and don't work with linux before.

Please help

Answer (score 2):

If you are familirar with Docker than install Docker for Windows and then try running pgAdmin4 docker image.
It will natively run pgAdmin4 in the browser.

Docker for Windows:
https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

pgAdmin4 Docker image: https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/

Comment: How can I download this image? Sorry but I'm not familiar with docker at all :( There are some examples of using... what exactly? There is no install and no package to download. Could you explain me how can I mount this image?